# Android emulator EGL14 attribute EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID does not work

Tags: android-emulator, android-4.3-jelly-bean, egl

I am working Android Emulator with 4.3 on Emulator

During create context of egl I give attribute EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID and it fails saying BAD_CONFIG?

Any idea why it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android Emulatior does not support full openGLES simulation. Hence some of the attributes are not supported